# Erro no group by de uma consulta no db2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

A Consulta:

```
Select ITEMNFS.Recnum, ITEMNFS.ITEM, sum(ITEMNFS.VL_TOTAL), sum(ITEMNFS.QTDE_FATUR), ITEM.PER_IPI 
from ITEMNFS 
inner join ITEM on ITEMNFS.ITEM = ITEM.ITEM inner join NFS on ((ITEMNFS.NRO_NFS = NFS.NRO_NFS) and (ITEMNFS.SERIE = NFS.SERIE)) 
where (NFS.DT_EMISSAO between '2017-12-01' and '2018-02-20') 
group by ITEMNFS.ITEM
```

O erro é o seguinte:

> SQL0119N  Uma expressão iniciada com "PER_IPI" especificada em uma
>   cláusula SELECT ou HAVING não foi especificada na cláusula GROUP BY ou
>   está em uma cláusula SELECT, HAVING ou ORDER BY com uma função de
>   coluna sem uma cláusula GROUP BY especificada.  SQLSTATE=42803

Answer (score 1):

O erro diz que você precisa adicionar todas as cláusulas que não são `sum()` ao `group by`. Tenta assim:

```
Select ITEMNFS.Recnum, ITEMNFS.ITEM, sum(ITEMNFS.VL_TOTAL), sum(ITEMNFS.QTDE_FATUR), ITEM.PER_IPI 
from ITEMNFS 
inner join ITEM on ITEMNFS.ITEM = ITEM.ITEM inner join NFS on ((ITEMNFS.NRO_NFS = NFS.NRO_NFS) and (ITEMNFS.SERIE = NFS.SERIE)) 
where (NFS.DT_EMISSAO between '2017-12-01' and '2018-02-20') 
group by ITEMNFS.Recnum, ITEMNFS.ITEM, ITEM.PER_IPI
```

Podes dar uma lida [nesse link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) sobre o `group by`, lá tem vários exemplos de *selects* com muitas colunas.

Comment: Beleza, funciona, mas não exatamente do jeito que eu quero. 

Eu precisaria agrupar e fazer os sum com todas as linhas que tenham ITEMNFS.ITEM iguais

Não sei se deu pra entender

Comment: Pra isso você precisaria remover as outras colunas (_ITEMNFS.Recnum_ e _ITEM.PER_IPI_) tanto do `select` quanto do `group by`